# In a specific row of a numpy array, how to find column indexes of the top 3 largest values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array X:

```
X = np.array([[4, 3, 5, 2],
              [9, 6, 7, 3],
              [8, 6, 7, 5],
              [3, 4, 5, 3],
              [5, 3, 2, 6]])
```

I want the indices of the top 3 greatest values in a row with index 1. The result of that would be :

```
[0,2,1]
```

I am relatively new to Python. I tried doing it with argsort, but am not able to do it for one specific row.

Comment: i am not sure how you get result `[0,2,1]` from a 5x4 matrix. For index 1 shoudn't you have 4 results

Comment: @Kenan That's the result from getting the indices of the three greatest items in row 1.

Comment: What have you actually tried? Show the thing that didn't work

Comment: You can first select out the row you want with `X[1,:]` then perform any operation you want on it. See the [indexing documentation for numpy here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more on this topic

Comment: @G.Anderson. You don't even need the `:`.

Comment: Without an attempt posted, the question sounds like "I'm new, gimme teh codez", which is off topic here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist true, but I find that being explicit in array slicing for beginners is more helpful in the long run

Comment: @G.Anderson. Fair point. It certainly leads to less confusion that way

Comment: "indices of the top 3 greatest values in a row with index 1" Okay, to make sure I understand: you want to get a specific row from the array; then you want to determine which of the values in that row are greatest; then you want to know the indices of those values. Correct? Okay, so what part of that don't you know how to do? What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I understand it looks like a very basic question. Actually, it is a part of something I was trying to do and got stuck. The row that I mention specifically, its index is calculated on the basis of the max sum of the rows. Whichever row has that, I then need to calculate the column indexes of the top 3 highest values. I will try to post a more detailed question and my attempt  next time onwards. Thank you for your attention to my post :)

Comment: That was a long speech that could have been averted by just showing your work. You are free to edit your question at any time to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argsort` on `axis=1` (by row) and then extract the last 3 indices for each row:

```
X.argsort(axis=1)[:,:-4:-1]

#[[2 0 1]
# [0 2 1]
# [0 2 1]
# [2 1 3]
# [3 0 1]]
```

Comment: Argpartition is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

```
X = np.array([[4, 3, 5, 2],
              [9, 6, 7, 3],
              [8, 6, 7, 5],
              [3, 4, 5, 3],
              [5, 3, 2, 6]])

# get top 3 values in the row with index 1
row_sorted = sorted(X[1], reverse=True)[0:3]

# Find the corresponding index of theses top 3 values
indexes = [list(X[1]).index(i) for i in row_sorted]
```

output:

```
[0, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For sufficiently large arrays, [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) will be the most efficient solution. It will place the last three elements of the sort indices in the right positions:

```
i = np.argpartition(x[1], [-3, -2, -1])[:-4:-1]
```

This behaves similarly to [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) except that only the selected indices are in the right place. All the other elements are only guaranteed to be in the correct side relative to each partition point, but not the exact position.

Comment: Good call, but maybe `X.argpartition(-3)[:,:-4:-1]` so it works for the entire array.

Comment: @Psidom. Sure. You want to explicitly include all the indices though if you want them to actually be sorted